# Do gate level simulations have any utilitly in the current highly complex digital circuit designs?

Tags: simulation, synthesis

Gate level simulation involves taking a netlist and annotating it with the delay information from a layout of the circuit. This information can be obtained after the floorplan and layout of circuit has been completed.

Electronic circuits today can be millions and millions of logic gates. They shall be implementing highly complex functions and even be implementing some complex features for power reduction and routing through complex network on chips. For something of this nature, a gate level simulation will run extremely slowly.

Taking into consideration the fact that functional verification is completed and timing closure is achieved, is there any benefit to carrying out a gate level simulation since it will require a lot of time and effort to make it work? I assume that no one carries it out anymore due to little value added, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing an FPGA design I think that timing closure would be enough.

When you are doing custom silicon however I think the manufacturing and NRE costs justify doing a full gate level simulation even if it takes a week to complete.

Comment: full custom digital or mixed signal? I did not think from the ASIC angle I guess.

Comment: I would add one exception : chasing a suspected synthesis or P&R tool bug. I've resorted to this once in a quarter century! : the time I found Xilinx XST synthesis using variable assignment syntax for signals passed to procedures. Wrecked a carefully pipelined multiplier! And fixed 3 major XST versions later.